# TeamCity + Allure

Tags: teamcity, allure

I'm evaluating the use of TeamCity, and I'm having problems integrating the Allure plugin.

Running server and agent on Win 8.1 x64.
Team City v9.1.3

Downloaded v2.1 of Allure plugin and commandline from https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-teamcity-plugin/releases (Release 2.1)

Unzipped and made sure to add Allure command line bin to my path. 
Uploaded the plugin zip through TeamCity plugin uploader.

At this point I was expecting to find Allure build step in my build steps but no.

What's going on?

Comment: Do you see allure plugin in `Administration -> Plugins List`?